# Auto-wiring object from imported dependency

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I would like to understand what is the case, when it says could not auto-wire on the object that came from added dependency.

Let's say I have a @Service class and that service cannot exist without SomeObect, that SomeObect is a class from the Jar i have imported. I do understand that I could create a method in the same class and annotate it with @Bean and return new SomeObject but is there any other way for @Autowire annotation to actually get that object from the context.

```
@Autowired
SomeObject someObject.
```

Comment: For spring to autowire a bean , the same should be made available in the application context. `SomeObject` will either need to have an annotation for `@ComponentScan` to detect and register the bean or it should be declared a bean using `@Bean` annotation / xml configuration. Without configuring `SomeObject` as a bean ,  it is not possible to get the object of that class from the application context

Comment: @R.G thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to add SomeObject to ApplicationContext, e.g. via @Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SomeObject someObject() {
    return new SomeObject();
  }

}
```

or via component scan:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "<package of SomeObject>")
public class ServiceConfiguration {


}
```